# Eigenvalues not sorted numpy eigh

Tags: python, numpy

I'm calculating the eigenvalues of a symmetric real matrix with eigh from numpy. I know that there are a bunch of similar questions online, but I didn't find a solution.

The eigh routine uses according to the doc a fortran routine that gives the eigenvalues in an ascending order. The transformation matrix in the new basis thus also contains a permutation matrix. My question is, if it is somehow possible to extract this permutation matrix from the transformation matrix, i.e. finding P in

U'=P U.

There seems to be a workaround in mathematica (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59172/should-eigenvalues-be-ordered), however, I don't have a license and I'm not able to translate the code given there.
An option would be to use eig which doesn't sort the eigenvalues, however, I found some sorting for very large matrices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show an [MCVE]: input matrix, output, and what you wanted to get instead. Make it a small example to play with.

Comment: Hmm I am not aware of any canonical order for the eigenvalues/eigenvectors. In the post you mention somebody prefers them ordered by value rather than absolute value. Is that also what you want? And if so may I ask why? Notice that since permutation matrices are orthogonal no matter the order of them if you put them in a matrix you get a unitary matrix.